# How to hide/remove blank cells in rdlc report

Tags: c#, rdlc

I am using a table to display my data in th rdlc report. I am using the "Hide Duplicates" property but that just display blank cells then. Is there any way to get rid of these blank cells.

[EXAMPLE.JPG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fld0D.jpg)

I have tried to hide it using the visibility expression

iif(Field!SCH.Value="",True,False)

but that doesn't work as the field is not original blank, the values are just hidden as they are duplicates.

Comment: Can you modify your SQL Query to eliminate the empty cells?  You need to look at the rdlc which is text to see how the cell is generated as well as the query (command text).

Comment: which control is that? a matrix, a tablix? grouping settings? probably best to clean up the source dataset and not rely on the "hide duplicates" feature here.

Comment: @dlatikay it's a tablix and I don't really have access to the data so I was hoping maybe I could get this cleaned up on rdlc itself. thanks though